# Xcode 15.2: Test app on older iOS versions (11, 12, 13) without downgrading?

Tags: swiftui, ios-simulator, xcode15

I want to test my app on iOS 11, 12, and 13 simulators  but I'm using Xcode 15.2, which doesn't include those versions by default However, I don't want to downgrade Xcode , can anyone provide solution for this

Testing iOS 11-13 App in Xcode 15.2 (No Downgrade): Help! Tried various official Apple documentation, development blogs, forums, etc

Answer (score 0):

Testing iOS apps across different versions is crucial for ensuring compatibility and a seamless user experience. While Xcode 15.2 may not include iOS 11, 12, and 13 simulators by default, you can still test your app on these versions without downgrading Xcode. Here's how:

**Download Additional Simulators via Xcode:**

- Open Xcode.
- Navigate to "Xcode" > "Preferences" from the menu bar.
- Choose the "Components" tab.
- Scroll down to find the simulator versions you need (iOS 11, 12, and 13).
- Download each simulator version by clicking on the respective download button.